# Set WPF Resources in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, resources

How do I do the following via C# (as I'm generating ListViews programatically):

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"/>
    </ListView.Resources>
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm still learning to WPF, but you might try this:

```
    ListView view = new ListView();
    view.Resources.Add(SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey, new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent));
    view.Resources.Add(SystemColors.ControlBrushKey, new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent));
```